# What diff algorithm relies on finding the longest common prefix and suffix and cursing on the middle substring?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, diff, git-diff

I can't remember where I read this years ago, but there's this variant of a `diff` algorithm for 2 lines, that finds the longest common prefix and suffix for the 2 lines, and then recurses on the remaining portion.

There might have been some kind of pivot element involved as well. I can't seem to find it on Google when I searched using the above description.

Is there a name for this `diff` algorithm?

Comment: I surmise you're looking for either [Ratcliff/Obershelp pattern recognition algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_pattern_matching) or [Myers algorithm](https://www.nathaniel.ai/myers-diff/)